# Crawler for performing reverse search and writing results into a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script which is able to perform reverse search in the website using the Name and Lid from a predefined CSV file. However, when the search is done then it can put the results containing Address and Phone Number adjacent to those Name and Lid creating a new CSV file. It is working errorlessly now. I tried to make the total process clean. Any suggestion to do betterment of this script will be highly appreciated. Here is the code I have tried with:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

with open("predefined.csv", "r") as f, open('newly_created.csv', 'w', newline='') as g:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    newfieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['Address', 'Phone']
    writer = csv.writer = csv.DictWriter(g, fieldnames = newfieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for entry in reader:

        Page = "https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/{}-{}".format(entry["Name"].replace(" ","-"), entry["Lid"])
        response = requests.get(Page)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"business-card")]')

        for title in tree.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"business-card")]'):
            Address= title.xpath('.//p[@class="address"]/span/text()')[0]
            Contact = title.xpath('.//p[@class="phone"]/text()')[0]

            print(Address,Contact)

            new_row = entry
            new_row['Address'] = Address
            new_row['Phone'] = Contact
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Here is the [link to the search criteria of "predefined.csv" file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rjzjsybgnj1c04/predefined%20content.txt?dl=0).

Here is the [link to the results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq66hj7kbohdqrx/Results.txt?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things we can do to improve the code:

- variable naming - try to be consistent with [`PEP8` naming suggestions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) - for instance:

  - `Page` should probably be `page` - or even better `url`
  - `Address` would be `address`
  - `Contact` would be `contact`
  - `f` can be `input_file`
  - `g` can be `output_file`
- `titles` variable is *never used*
- move the url format string into a *constant*
- you don't need `writer = csv.writer = csv.DictWriter(...)` - just assign the `writer` to the `DictWriter` instance directly
- since you are crawling the same domain, re-using [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) instance should have a positive impact on performance
- use `.findtext()` method instead of `xpath()` and then getting the first item
- I would also create a separate `crawl` function to keep the web-scraping logic separate

Here is the modified code with the above and other improvements combined:

```
import csv

import requests
from lxml import html


URL_TEMPLATE = "https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/{}-{}"


def crawl(entries):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        for entry in entries:
            url = URL_TEMPLATE.format(entry["Name"].replace(" ", "-"), entry["Lid"])
            response = session.get(url)
            tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

            titles = tree.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"business-card")]')
            for title in titles:
                address = title.findtext('.//p[@class="address"]/span')
                contact = title.findtext('.//p[@class="phone"]')

                print(address, contact)

                entry['Address'] = address
                entry['Phone'] = contact
                yield entry


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("predefined.csv", "r") as input_file, open('newly_created.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
        field_names = reader.fieldnames + ['Address', 'Phone']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=field_names)
        writer.writeheader()

        for entry in crawl(reader):
            writer.writerow(entry)
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your elaborative review and the epic code. I tested it just now and found it working like as your code always does. Btw, is it a good idea to write the results creating another csv file other than the existing one?

Comment: @SMth80 you can do either of them technically, but I would probably keep input and output files as separate files just in case there is something wrong in the logic of the program and I don't want to have my file in an intermediate state. Thanks!

Comment: @Shahin yup, I've already seen this post - nice question. And you've got really good reviews - actually don't have anything valuable to add. Thanks for heads up!